# what's the benefit of Boost.Functional in comparison with Boost.Bind?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, boost-functional

I've never used [Boost.Functional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/functional/index.html), only briefly read its documentation. Looks like it's an improvement to Standard <*[functional](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/)*> header.

An example on the main page of [Boost.Functional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/functional/index.html) (**Usage** section) was chosen as an introduction to the library. The same can be done easier using [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/bind.html) (or [Boost.Lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#lambda.bind_expressions)). Also, **Boost.Bind** is an excellent alternative to other tools from <*functional*> header.

I'm curious, is there anything from **Boost.Functional** or STL <*functional*> header that cannot be done by **Boost.Bind**? Or any other benefits of **Boost.Functional**?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/functional/index.html, it says:

> The header functional.hpp provides enhancements to the function object
>   adapters specified in the C++ Standard Library (sections 20.3.5,
>   through to 20.3.8). The enhancements are principally possible due to
>   two changes:
>
> - We use the Boost call_traits templates to avoid the problem of references to references, and to improve the efficiency of parameter passing.
> - We use two function object traits class templates to avoid the need for ptr_fun with the adapters in this library.
>
> #### Usage
>
> Using these adapters should be pretty much the same as using the
>   standard function object adapters; the only differences are that you
>   need to write boost:: instead of std::, and that you will get fewer
>   headaches.

No one uses "ptr_fun" anymore (when you have Boost.Bind), so that just leaves dealing with "references to references"
Does that answer your question?

Comment: Sorry, but not yet. "We use the Boost call_traits templates to avoid the problem of references to references...", so it's nothing special to Boost.Functional. Was your answer "there's no benefit"?